# What happens after a border conviction?

Tags: united-states, immigration, borders

This recent [Article Here](https://www.usatoday.com/story/news/2018/06/21/trumps-zero-tolerance-border-prosecutions-led-time-served-and-10-fee/722237002/) raises the question of what happens after a US border conviction.

> On Monday, (6-18-18) agents brought a Honduran man, Mariano Torres-Perdomo, into court to face a misdemeanor charge of entering the country illegally. Border agents had caught him two days earlier crossing into Texas with his 6-year-old son. He quickly pleaded guilty...(he) was sentenced to time served and a $10 fee.

Presumably, he was turned over for deportation processing. So, after pleading guilty, would Torres-Perdomo have further judicial or administrative hearings before being physically removed to his home country?

The reason I wonder, is because the BCP and DHS seem to be suggesting that detentions prior to removal may take weeks or months.

The article actually raises a lot of other questions, but I'd like to focus on this first.

I'm not sure that this should be in Law SE or Politics SE, as it might have a home in either or both- feel free to migrate to Politics

Comment: FWIW, I think this is an appropriate forum to raise this question.

Answer (score 2):

> So, after pleading guilty, would Torres-Perdomo have further judicial
>   or administrative hearings before being physically removed to his home
>   country?

No. All that would have to be done is for DHS to arrange transportation to his home country from the USA. The guilty plea would consent to deportation without further hearing.

> The reason I wonder, is because the BCP and DHS seem to be suggesting
>   that detentions prior to removal may take weeks or months.

I think that this is in cases where there is not a guilty plea, for example, where an asylum claim is made by the person detained.

Comment: I wish that you could provide a citation. In FY 2016 ICE AIR flew 236 flights to Honduras, so I wouldn't think that transportation arrangement would be very time consuming. In the meanwhile, one wonders what becomes of his son?

Comment: @BobE I don't know the answer to what becomes of his son.